# Bad Access on delegate only on iPhone 4S

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates

My application crashes after random times when delegate is called (inside IBAction method) but only on iPhone 4S in Simulator. Every other newer iPhone works great.

```
@propert (assign, nonatomic) id <MyDelegate> delegate;
```

Of course I am using ARC. What can be the reason?

**SOLVED:**
Argument passing in delegate method in some conditions was unintentionally released from memory. Changing it to strong type helped.

Comment: Many... dead reference mainly. Could you post some code, call stack, error logs of the class that uses this delegate and of the MyDelegate protocle declaration

Comment: Added some code like you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you are using `assign`. This basically *means* "crash me". If your `delegate` goes out of existence, you are left pointing to garbage, and any attempt to access that garbage will result in a crash. In effect, you have thrown away the advantage that ARC gives you.

To restore that advantage, use `weak` instead. Now if your `delegate` goes out of existence, you will have `nil` and can proceed in good order.

Having gotten rid of the crash, you can now check for `nil` and try to figure out *why* your `delegate` has gone out of existence when you evidently don't expect it to. Keep in mind that the problem you are seeing is what we call "diagnostic"; the delegate may have gone out of existence long ago, or it may never have been assigned in the first place, but figuring that out is a completely separate matter.